# How to authorize Google API without user interaction in 2020?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am using a simple script to transfer data to google drive. The script is managed by Cron (independently of the user). How to authenticate google api without user interaction? There used to be a `oauth2client` (`SignedJwtAssertionCredentials`) library in Python, but it is no longer supported.

Comment: In your case, I would like to propose to use the service account. When the service account is used, the user is not required to retrieve the code with the browser. About the sample script of python and how to use it for the service account, you can see it at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552976 If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Ok, so there is a new lib `google-auth`. Thanks a lot. Google docs sucks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention