# (Python, no error but doesn't work) Google drive API can't upload file

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

Recently I am doing my side project, hoping to upload a excel file to my Google drive account by using Python. I use the code chatGPT suggested, however, there is no error in the code but I just could not successfully upload the file (could not find the file in my drive)

I hope there are experts who can help with the answer, thank you very much!

Here are my codes:

```
import os
import datetime
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

path_JSON = r'C:\Users\CY Chang\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\SideProjects\automate-update-excel-files-76a7ac1bd37f.json'
path_file = r'C:\Users\CY Chang\OneDrive\Desktop\filefolder\file\updatedfile.xlsx'

try:
    # Setting Google Drive API cred
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        path_JSON,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    )

    # Setting Google Drive API
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    # Create Google Drive catalog
    folder_metadata = {
        'name': 'Daily_Uploads',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    folder = drive_service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    folder_id = folder.get('id')

    # Upload Excel file to Google Drive
    file_metadata = {
        'name': f'Daily_Upload_{datetime.date.today()}.xlsx',
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(path_file, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

    print(f'File ID: {file.get("id")}')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

- Currently I had tried:

1. Checked out my Google Drive API.Since I tried many times, there are 40 requests and no errors.
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOF9.png)
2. Checked out my Goole Drive API access rights. My assigned role for myself is"owmer", should I add something like editor?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8dP.png)
3. Also I had tried the others solutions chatGPT provided, such as checking JSON file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that the file is uploaded to the drive of the service account with the service account. The drive of the service account is different from your Google account. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to see the uploaded file in your Google Drive of your account, I thought that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552976 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike OMG thank you! I am sorry that I did not found your previous solution, which immediately solve my question. I had been stuck here for several days...Anyway, thanks again for saving me in such a short time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question.